# CMakeLists: only link library if Raspberry Pi (or equivalent condition)

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that I want to run on both a desktop/laptop (x64) and a Raspberry Pi (armhf). There's a node in my package that has to be run on the Raspberry Pi. It uses the wiringPi library. Obviously, doing `catkin_make` on something other than a RPi results in an error, so at the moment I just comment out those lines.

I'd like to find a way to only execute `target_link_libraries()` if the current computer/architecture/distro matches that of the RPi.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256744/cmakelists:-only-link-library-if-raspberry-pi-(or-equivalent-condition)/) by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2017-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-12**:
@Chris_: this is really a CMake question, and not related to ROS per se (catkin == essentially CMake in this case). I'd advise you to do a (google) search for keywords like "cmake detect architecture" or "cmake detect raspberry pi". You'll probably find a solution much faster that way.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2017-03-12**:
@gvdhoorn yeah I figured it wasn't strictly ROS-related, but I thought I'd see if people went through the same stuff here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add an if - Else - endif clause in your CMakeLists.txt using a self defined variable, e.g. IS_RASP, with different target_link_libraries commands in if and Else.

When calling Into catkin_make you can call it without additional arg on your Host anderen with `catkin_make -DIS_RASP=1` in your device. Note you can pass Command Line args to cmake when calling it via catkin_make using the -D Just Like you would so in plain cmake.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1